# Content isn't going in correct column on a 2 column page

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I am trying to make two separate columns of content based on the 'ReportItemCategoryID'. If != 8, it goes in the left column. If it == 8, it goes in the right column. The two column formatting is working, but I have run into an issue that I can't figure out. There are 5 pieces of content that should be in the left column ("col1") and 1 that should be in right column ("col2"). When the foreach loops execute, they list the div ID's correctly (5 have "col1" and 1 has "col2"). Can anyone explain to me why 4 of the categories that come through the first foreach loop appear in the second column and not the first one?

**This is the HTML**

*The "span6" class declares the width for its content. The "pull-left" class formats its content as float left.*

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
        @foreach (var group in Model.Where(i => i.Active && i.ReportItemCategory.Active && i.Visible && i.ReportItemCategoryID!=8).GroupBy(i => i.ReportItemCategoryID).OrderBy(i => i.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name))
{
        <div id="col1" class="span6 pull-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="input-append">

                        <div rel="tooltip" title="@group.First().ReportItemCategory.Description">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/folder-horizontal.png")" alt="Folder" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                            <span>@group.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name</span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            @foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.Name))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <div class="input-append" rel="tooltip" title="@item.Description">
                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/chart.png")" alt="Report" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:newPopup('@Url.Action("ViewReport", "Reporting", new { id = item.ReportItemID })');return false;">@item.Name</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

}
@foreach (var group in Model.Where(i => i.Active && i.ReportItemCategory.Active && i.Visible && i.ReportItemCategoryID==8).GroupBy(i => i.ReportItemCategoryID).OrderBy(i => i.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name))
{
        <div id="col2" class="span6 pull-left">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="input-append">

                        <div rel="tooltip" title="@group.First().ReportItemCategory.Description">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/folder-horizontal.png")" alt="Folder" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                            <span>@group.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name</span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            @foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.Name))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <div class="input-append" rel="tooltip" title="@item.Description">
                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/chart.png")" alt="Report" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:newPopup('@Url.Action("ViewReport", "Reporting", new { id = item.ReportItemID })');return false;">@item.Name</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
}
</div>
```

**Expected Result** *Not to scale*

```
+-------------------------------------+
|+---------------+   +---------------+|
||               |   |               ||
||               |   |               ||
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |                    |
|+---------------+                    |
|+---------------+                    |
||               |                    |
||               |                    |
|+---------------+                    |
|+---------------+                    |
||               |                    |
||               |                    |
|+---------------+                    |
|+---------------+                    |
||               |                    |
||               |                    |
|+---------------+                    |
|+---------------+                    |
||               |                    |
||               |                    |
|+---------------+                    |
+-------------------------------------+
```

**Actual Result** *Not to scale*

```
+-------------------------------------+
|+---------------+   +---------------+|
||               |   |               ||
||               |   |               ||
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |   |               ||
||               |   |               ||
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |   |               ||
||               |   |               ||
||               |   +---------------+|
||               |   +---------------+|
|+---------------+   |               ||
|                    |               ||
|                    +---------------+|
|                    +---------------+|
|                    |               ||
|                    |               ||
|                    +---------------+|
|                                     |
|                                     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the col1 and col2 divs outside of the foreach loop. This made sure that each foreach loop was ran within its respective div. I am posting this answer in case there is anyone else with this same problem.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
 <div id="col1" class="span6 pull-left">
 @foreach (var group in Model.Where(i => i.Active && i.ReportItemCategory.Active && i.Visible && i.ReportItemCategoryID!=8).GroupBy(i => i.ReportItemCategoryID).OrderBy(i => i.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name))
{

            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="input-append">

                        <div rel="tooltip" title="@group.First().ReportItemCategory.Description">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/folder-horizontal.png")" alt="Folder" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                            <span>@group.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name</span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            @foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.Name))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <div class="input-append" rel="tooltip" title="@item.Description">
                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/chart.png")" alt="Report" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:newPopup('@Url.Action("ViewReport", "Reporting", new { id = item.ReportItemID })');return false;">@item.Name</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>


} 
</div>
<div id="col2" class="span6 pull-left">
@foreach (var group in Model.Where(i => i.Active && i.ReportItemCategory.Active && i.Visible && i.ReportItemCategoryID==8).GroupBy(i => i.ReportItemCategoryID).OrderBy(i => i.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name))
{

            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">
                    <div class="input-append">

                        <div rel="tooltip" title="@group.First().ReportItemCategory.Description">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/folder-horizontal.png")" alt="Folder" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                            <span>@group.FirstOrDefault().ReportItemCategory.Name</span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav nav-list">
                            @foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.Name))
                            {
                                <li>
                                    <div class="input-append" rel="tooltip" title="@item.Description">
                                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/img/chart.png")" alt="Report" style="margin-bottom:-3px;"/>
                                        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:newPopup('@Url.Action("ViewReport", "Reporting", new { id = item.ReportItemID })');return false;">@item.Name</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

}
</div>
</div>
```